# Find $\int g(x)g'(x)\text{ dx}$ where $g'(x)$ is continous

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

$$\int g(x)g'(x)\text{ dx}$$

I'm not sure how to evaluate this.

I know $\int g(x)\text{ dx} = G(x)$, and I know $\int g'(x)\text{ dx} = g(x)$,

but how can I break up this integral to solve the main integral?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use $u$-substitution.

Let $u = g(x)$. Then $g^{\prime}(x) = \dfrac{\text{d}u}{\text{d}x}$, so we may write $\text{d}u = g^{\prime}(x) \text{ d}x$. Hence, our integral is 
$$\int u \text{ d}u = \dfrac{u^2}{2} + C = \dfrac{[g(x)]^2}{2}+C\text{.}$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. One may recall that, using  the chain rule,
$$
\left[(g(x))^\alpha \right]'=\alpha \cdot g'(x)\cdot(g(x))^{\alpha-1}.
$$ applying it with $\alpha=2$ gives the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Integration by parts?

$$\int g(x)(g'(x)\ dx)=g(x)g(x)-\int g'(x)(g(x)\ dx)$$

$$2\int g(x)g'(x)\ dx=(g(x))^2+c$$

Comment: Haven't learned it

Comment: @KSplitX Then you'll probably learn it eventually.  Anyways, the other answers are probably good enough for you.